# Is there any documentation for Jellyfish?

Tags: python, string

silly question. Does anyone know where to find any documentation for the string matching library, jellyfish? I have installed it, but can't for the life of me find any documentaion....

Comment: [I think that could be pretty much it](https://github.com/sunlightlabs/jellyfish)

Comment: Haha, so trial and error it is then!

Comment: Do you have view on whether this is a good package for string matching?

Comment: Not really! Does it look like it’ll work for what you’re trying to do?

Comment: Well i have a huge list of unclean strings, and when they are (in reality) the same I want to be able to identify them as such. e.g. 'Jonas Short (501)' 'Junas Shrt' 'jon. short' - these in fact represent the same item in my data set. Not sure that re's are the best way to go about this....

Comment: Actually I'm not sure that jellyfish algorithms are right. It is calculating the damerau_levenshtein_distance as 3, when it should be 2 when comparing the following strings CA, ABC

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know this is closed, but I found myself with the same problem while working on a fuzzy string matching project recently. As others have mentioned, the official documentation on the jellyfish library is rather sparse. However, I did find [this Ipython Notebook](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/gist/MajorGressingham/7691723) by [Rory Creedon](https://twitter.com/M_Gressingham) which gives both a broad overview of jellyfish's capabilities as well as some specific examples of implementation. More jellyfish examples from Rory can be found [here](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/gist/MajorGressingham/7801647) and [here](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/gist/MajorGressingham/7876252).

Comment: Thansk Kirk! I actually posted the question and made those resources in response to the fact that there basically are no real docs!

Answer (score 3):

After looking around, I have found two good places for documentation. The first is [HERE](https://github.com/sunlightlabs/jellyfish), which is the github code of jellyfish. You can read the code on github and the documentation that the library has. The second place that I found which does not have as much documentation can be found [at python.org](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/jellyfish/0.1.2), which has some information on the library.

Answer (score 2):

For people that find this question, jellyfish is now fully documented here:

http://jellyfish.readthedocs.org/en/latest/